# Listview zoom and animation in Android

Tags: android, listview, gallery

Hello Please help me with an Issue, I have a gallery to which i had applied animation. What is actually does it zoom the current/clicked view.

I want that same behaviour in my listview, for example i have

```
PLAY
SETTINGS
QUIT
```

So when i click PLAY it should have a zoom effect **PLAY**

Please guide me..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view that you are trying to implement can be done with gallaryview in android. So if you can modify gallery then you can get this behaviour, if it seems tough that just grab the opensource coverflow code and modify it a bit to get desired behaviour

Answer (score 1):

you can have an integer variable to hold, currently focused element in list, and in your adapter's getView method, check this variable with position and on match can return a different view, on focus change, reset position holder value, and call adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();